# What are noise reduction techniques implemented in code, if not graph beautifiers?

Tags: python, noise, c, embedded-systems

How does Noise Reduction techniques implemented in code help us?

I am working on an analog accelerometer and while I log the data, I see noise in the data values that is almost constant and in the range of 0-50g. I am able to register shock values beyond the range of 50g. Other than reducing the noise from actual physical system I don't see any use of implementing noise reduction in my code. May I please know what I am missing here and how the noise reduction technique will actually help me?

Comment: There are some real time software techniques that can help reduce the noise. The vanilla technique would be a order 1 IIR low pass filter which will smooth your data at the cost of some mild delay. If your sensor has a systematic bias (which looks plausible regarding your post) then you might just substract the bias and it would be a noise reduction technique. But if you want to apply any treatment to your acceleration and let's say you want to integrate it for some position estimation then you should filter, because then you will also integrate the noise in your measurement.

Comment: Ohh, okay noted, I'll check the order 1 IIR low pass filer, thank you for your suggestions @NokiYola